# PHP Mail Without STMP: mail() and PHPMailer Echo Failure upon Send

Tags: php, email, localhost, phpmailer, bluehost

I am trying to send an email from our website, hosted on BlueHost, that includes an attachment. We found out that as of August 2015, our original script would no longer send emails to our email.

Fast forward to now, we are trying to fix this email issue, but are having no luck. Originally, our code was using the old mail() approach. Below is the attempted fix to this approach (which returns no PHP/log errors):

```php
<?php
if(!isset($_POST["email"]) && !isset($_POST["name"]))
{
    echo "Error: Form Not Submitted.\n Name and email are mandatory!Please Click the back button to return to the website.\n";
    //Set Variables
    $company = $_POST["company"];
    $address = $_POST["address"];
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $position = $_POST["position"];
    $visitor_email = $_POST["email"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];
    $submitVar = $_POST["submit"];
    echo "$company, $address, $phone, $name, $position, $visitor_email, $message \r\n";
}
else{
    //Set Variables
    $company = $_POST["company"];
    $address = $_POST["address"];
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $position = $_POST["position"];
    $visitor_email = $_POST["email"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];
    echo "$company, $address, $phone, $name, $position, $visitor_email, $message \r\n";

    if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
    {
        echo "Bad email value!";
        exit;
    }

    //***Lay out Message***//   
    $to = "example@att.net";
    $email_from = $visitor_email;
    $email_subject = "Website Form Submission from $company";
    $email_body = "Dear Email Target,\n\n $message\n\nSincerely,\n\n$name\n$position\n\n$company\n$address\n$phone";

    //***Attatch the file***//
    $filename = $_FILES['attachment1']['tmp_name'];
    $filetype = $_FILES['attachment1']['tmp_type'];
    $filesize = $_FILES['attachment1']['tmp_size'];  // get size of the file for size validation
    if($filesize > 0){
        $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
        $content = fread($handle, $filesize);
        fclose($handle);
        $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
    }

    //*** Establish Boundary ***//  
    $boundary = md5(date('r', time()));

    //***Start Header***//
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers = "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion()."\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: ".$name." <".$email_from.">\r\n";
    $headers .= "To: ".$email."\r\n";
    $headers .= "Subject: $email_subject\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$visitor_email."\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed"; 
    $headers .= "boundary = \"".$boundary."\"\r\n\r\n";

    //***Message Section***//
    $body = "--$boundary\r\n"; 
        $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"; 
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base7\r\n\r\n";  
        $body .= $email_body;

    //***Attachment Section***//;
    if($filesize > 0){
        $body .= "--$boundary\r\n"; 
        $body .="Content-Type:".$filetype."; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; 
        $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename."\r\n"; 
        $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"; 
        $body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000, 99999)."\r\n\r\n";  
        $body .= $attachment."\r\n\r\n"; // Attaching the encoded file with email 
    }

    //***End Email***///
    $body .= "--$boundary--";

    //Send the email!
    $test = mail($to, $email_subject, $body, $headers);
    if($test){
        echo "TRUE";
        //done. redirect to thank-you page.
        header("Location: ./Sales_Quotes.html"); 
        echo '<h5 class="contentHeader simple">Form Submitted!</h5>';
        /* Redirect browser */
        exit();/*Good Practice*/
    } else {
        die("Error: PHP mail() failure!\r\n"
        .$to."\r\n"
        .$email_subject."\r\n"
        .$body."\r\n"
        .$headers."\r\n");
    }
}

// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
    $injections = array('(\n+)',
      '(\r+)',
      '(\t+)',
      '(%0A+)',
      '(%0D+)',
      '(%08+)',
      '(%09+)'
      );
    $inject = join('|', $injections);
    $inject = "/$inject/i";
    if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Both a localhost running Debian 10.2 and BlueHost tell me that the mail() function fails when I call it. Where did I go wrong? As I was getting nowhere on this after 2 days of work, since everyone seems to want me to use PHPMailer, I also created a second script with the PHPMailer approach and it also fails the exact same way (no log/php errors, telling me that the call failed):

```php
<?php
require_once './PHPMailer.php';
require_once './Exception.php';
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
if(!isset($_POST["email"]) && !isset($_POST["name"]))
{
    echo "Error: Form Not Submitted.\n Name and email are mandatory!Please Click the back button to return to the website.\n";
    //Set Variables
    $company = $_POST["company"];
    $address = $_POST["address"];
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $position = $_POST["position"];
    $visitor_email = $_POST["email"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];
    $submitVar = $_POST["submit"];
    echo "$company, $address, $phone, $name, $position, $visitor_email, $message \r\n";
}
else{
    //***Set Variables***//
    $company = $_POST["company"];
    $address = $_POST["address"];
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $position = $_POST["position"];
    $visitor_email = $_POST["email"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];
    echo "$company, $address, $phone, $name, $position, $visitor_email, $message \r\n";

    if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
    {
        echo "Bad email value!";
        exit;
    }

    //***Lay out Message***//   
    $to = "example@att.net";
    $email_from = $visitor_email;
    $email_subject = "Website Form Submission from $company";
    $email_body = "Dear Target,\n\n $message\n\nSincerely,\n\n$name\n$position\n\n$company\n$address\n$phone";

    //***Upload the file***//
    $filename = $_FILES['attachment1']['tmp_name'];
    $filetype = $_FILES['attachment1']['type'];
    $filesize = $_FILES['attachment1']['size'];  // get size of the file for size validation
    if($filesize > 0){
        $attachment = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $_FILES['attachment1']['name']));
        if (!(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment1']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))){
            echo "Failed to Upload File Properly.";
        }
    }

    //***Create the PHPMailer Message***//:
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail -> setFrom($email_from,$name);
    $mail -> To = "sietins@sietins.com";
    $mail -> addAddress("example@att.net", "Mr. Example");
    $mail -> Subject = $email_subject;
    $mail -> Body = $email_body;
    if($filesize > 0){
        //***Attach the file***//
        $mail ->addAttachment($uploadfile,$filename);
    }

    //***Send the email!***//
    if(!$mail->send()){
        echo "TRUE";
        //done. redirect to thank-you page.
        header("Location: ./Sales_Quotes.html"); 
        echo '<h5 class="contentHeader simple">Form Submitted!</h5>';
        /* Redirect browser */
        exit();/*Good Practice*/
    } else {
        die("Error: PHP mail() failure!\r\n"
        .$to."\r\n"
        .$email_subject."\r\n"
        .$email_body."\r\n");
    }
}

// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
    $injections = array('(\n+)',
      '(\r+)',
      '(\t+)',
      '(%0A+)',
      '(%0D+)',
      '(%08+)',
      '(%09+)'
      );
    $inject = join('|', $injections);
    $inject = "/$inject/i";
    if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Is there any simple solution/correction to the above that fulfills the following requirements?:

- **No SMTP**. Localhost preferred.
- Quick/Easy Setup
- **Must** support an
  **optional attachment** from user
- **Must** be viable for BlueHost.

Note that this is for a small business in the manufacturing industry.
I'm at my wits end and I've already spent too much time on this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For one thing, you're outputting before header. Enable error reporting, check what they are and start again.

Comment: One of the many problems with the `mail()` function, is that indeed it gives you no feedback on why it might be failing. The place to look for what happened to your messages is your local mail server's log files. Given that all the mail function does is call a sendmail binary which opens a synchronous SMTP connection to localhost, you should find that SMTP to localhost directly from PHPMailer is a lot faster and much easier to diagnose (because you can enable `SMTPDebug`). Also you are getting no error message because you're not printing one! Echo `$mail->ErrorInfo` if your call to send fails.

Comment: @Synchro: Added ```$mail->ErrorInfo;```, no other output than what I already output. It simply just fails.

Comment: You're asking PHPMailer to throw exceptions (by passing `true` to the constructor), but you have no try/catch block surrounding it, so your script will die (with a fatal uncaught exception) as soon as you call `send()`, and it will never reach your `echo` output for either success or failure.

Comment: ```try{
  if(!$mail->send()){
   echo "TRUE";
   //done. redirect to thank-you page.
   header("Location: ./Sales_Quotes.html"); 
   echo '<h5 class="contentHeader simple">Form Submitted!</h5>';
   /* Redirect browser */
   exit();/*Good Practice*/
  } else {
   die("Error: PHP mail() failure!\r\n"
   ."\r\n");
   echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
  }
 }
 catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage();  //PHPMailer error messages
 }
 catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();  // other error messages
 }
```
you mean like this? Just tried and still no errors.

Comment: Also just tried it by simplifying the statement to just the send and echos (with the try and catch) and still nothing except my "PHP mail() failure!" message.

Answer (score 0):

After quite a lot of testing and debugging, the final code came out to be the following:

```php
<?php
require_once './PHPMailer.php';
require_once './Exception.php';
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
if(!isset($_POST["email"]) && !isset($_POST["name"]))
{
    echo "Error: Form Not Submitted.\n Name and email are mandatory! Please Click the back button to return to the website.\n";
    //Set Variables
    $company = $_POST["company"];
    $address = $_POST["address"];
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $position = $_POST["position"];
    $visitor_email = $_POST["email"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];
    $submitVar = $_POST["submit"];
    echo "$company, $address, $phone, $name, $position, $visitor_email, $message \r\n";
}
else{
    //***Set Variables***//
    $company = $_POST["company"];
    $address = $_POST["address"];
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $position = $_POST["position"];
    $visitor_email = $_POST["email"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];
    //echo "$company, $address, $phone, $name, $position, $visitor_email, $message \r\n";

    if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
    {
        echo "Bad email value!";
        exit;
    }

    //***Lay out Message***//   
    $to = "example@att.net";
    $email_from = $visitor_email;
    $email_subject = "Website Form Submission from $company";
    $email_body = "Dear Target Company,\n\n $message\n\nSincerely,\n\n$name\n$position\n\n$company\n$address\n$phone";

    //***Upload the file***//
    $filename = $_FILES['attachment1']['tmp_name'];
    $filetype = $_FILES['attachment1']['type'];
    $filesize = $_FILES['attachment1']['size'];  // get size of the file for size validation
    if($filesize > 0){
        $attachment = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $_FILES['attachment1']['name']));
        if (!(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment1']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))){
            echo "Failed to Upload File Properly.";
        }
    }

    //***Create the PHPMailer Message***//:
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail -> setFrom($email_from,$name);
    $mail -> To = "example@att.net";
    $mail -> addAddress("example@att.net", "Mr Example");
    $mail -> Subject = $email_subject;
    $mail -> Body = $email_body;
    if($filesize > 0){
        //***Attach the file***//
        $mail ->addAttachment($uploadfile,$filename);
    }

    //***Send the email!***//
    try{
        $mail->send();
        //done. redirect to thank-you page.
        header("Location: ./Sales_Quotes.html"); 
        echo '<h5 class="contentHeader simple">Form Submitted!</h5>';
        /* Redirect browser */
        exit();/*Good Practice*/
    }
    catch (phpmailerException $e) {
        echo "Error: PHPMailer failure!: ";
        echo $e->errorMessage();  //PHPMailer error messages
        echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Error: PHPMailer failure!: ";
        echo $e->getMessage();  // other error messages
        echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
}

// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
    $injections = array('(\n+)',
      '(\r+)',
      '(\t+)',
      '(%0A+)',
      '(%0D+)',
      '(%08+)',
      '(%09+)'
      );
    $inject = join('|', $injections);
    $inject = "/$inject/i";
    if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Turns out many of the examples and answers out there for PHPMailer are mis-typed or bad references. For anyone looking to NOT use SMTP and include an attachment, this code should work (minimally send the email) on BlueHost.

Answer (score -1):

Tye to put this at start and at end of mail output:
Ob_start();
Ob_end_clean();